# handling enormous nested datasets in R / tidyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

- I have data files from word recognition simulations with neural networks.
- The network has a lexicon of 1000 words.
- The output has 30,000 nodes -- 30 copies of each word at a different alignment.
- I run separate simulations with each word as the Input (1000 simulations). The output is a 100-step time series like this (here showing 2 Input examples (ark, bark), with 4 of the Copies for each word, tracking only 4 words, and showing only 5 time steps)

[Edit: 3 May 2021, dataset now includes realistic conditions that previous solutions could not handle. I apologize for changing the data, but I don't see a better way to clarify the gap in the previously suggested solution.]

```
xf = read.table(header=T, sep=",", text="
Input,Time,Word,Copy1,Copy2,Copy3,Copy30
ark,10,ark,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1
ark,20,ark,0.0,0.5,0.55,0.01
ark,30,ark,0.01,0.1,0.2,0.05
ark,40,ark,0.02,0.3,0.5,0.1
ark,50,ark,0.01,0.2,0.4,-0.1
ark,10,ad,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1
ark,20,ad,0.0,0.01,0.02,0.01
ark,30,ad,0.01,0.03,0.1,0.04
ark,40,ad,0.02,0.12,0.15,0.04
ark,50,ad,0.01,0.01,0.05,0.02
ark,10,bark,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1
ark,20,bark,0.02,0.12,0.1,0.01
ark,30,bark,0.03,0.15,0.12,0.02
ark,40,bark,0.02,0.22,0.1,0.03
ark,50,bark,0.01,0.1,0.05,0.02
ark,10,bar,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1
ark,20,bar,0.01,0.1,0.02,-0.05
ark,30,bar,0.01,0.12,0.03,0
ark,40,bar,0.02,0.15,0.03,0.01
ark,50,bar,0.01,0.05,0.02,0.01
bark,10,ark,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1
bark,20,ark,0.0,0.04,0.05,0.01
bark,30,ark,0.01,0.08,0.1,0.05
bark,40,ark,0.02,0.05,0.2,0.1
bark,50,ark,0.01,0.01,0.3,-0.1
bark,10,ad,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1
bark,20,ad,0.0,0.01,0.01,0.01
bark,30,ad,0.01,0.02,0.05,0.04
bark,40,ad,0.02,0.03,0.06,0.04
bark,50,ad,0.01,0.02,0.01,0.02
bark,10,bark,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1
bark,20,bark,0.02,0.15,0.1,0.01
bark,30,bark,0.03,0.3,0.12,0.02
bark,40,bark,0.02,0.7,0.1,0.03
bark,50,bark,0.01,0.7,0.05,0.02
bark,10,bar,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1
bark,20,bar,0.01,0.13,0.04,-0.05
bark,30,bar,0.01,0.25,0.06,0
bark,40,bar,0.02,0.4,0.08,0.01
bark,50,bar,0.01,0.35,0.01,0.01
") %>% arrange(Input,Word,Time)
```

I want to reduce this data in 2 ways.

(1) For each Input x Word combination, select **one** Copy for a word based on maximum values over the whole time series, and

(2) based on maximum values for the retained Copies (1 per Input x Word), reduce to the 'topX' Words.

---

My original question was unclear and became very unwieldy. @DanChaltiel provided partial answers using pivot_longer that came quite close to the completely solution, but I couldn't explain the first reduction clearly enough. So I broke that into a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67351185) where @akrun extended @DanChaltiel's solution like this, solving the first part (updated on 3 May 2021 to reflect repairs to the solution):

```
library(tidyverse)
# Reduce data to one Copy of each Input x Word combination
# based on maxima for entire time series, no matter what
# Time those maxima occur. Using pivot_longer was due to 
# answer from @DanChaltiel, but getting it to work on 
# Input x Word maxima over the whole time series (rather 
# than maxima of Input x Word x Time) was due to @akrun 
# for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67351185/
xf2 <- xf %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Copy'), names_to = 'copy_name', 
               values_to = 'Value') %>% 
  group_by(Input, Time, Word) %>% 
  arrange(Value) %>%
  slice(if(all(Value <= 0)) n() 
        else tail(which(Value > 0), 1))%>% 
  group_by(Input, Word) %>% 
  mutate(copy_name = copy_name[which.max(Value)]) %>%
  ungroup

print((xf2 %>% arrange(Input, Word)), n = nrow(xf2)) # print all rows

# A tibble: 40 x 5
# Input  Time Word  copy_name Value
# <fct> <int> <fct> <chr>     <dbl>
# 1 ark       10 ad    Copy3     -0.1 
# 2 ark       20 ad    Copy3      0.02
# 3 ark       30 ad    Copy3      0.1 
# 4 ark       40 ad    Copy3      0.15
# 5 ark       50 ad    Copy3      0.05
# 6 ark       10 ark   Copy3     -0.1 
# 7 ark       20 ark   Copy3      0.55
# 8 ark       30 ark   Copy3      0.2 
# 9 ark       40 ark   Copy3      0.5 
# 10 ark      50 ark   Copy3      0.4 
# 11 ark      10 bar   Copy2     -0.1 
# 12 ark      20 bar   Copy2      0.1 
# 13 ark      30 bar   Copy2      0.12
# 14 ark      40 bar   Copy2      0.15
# 15 ark      50 bar   Copy2      0.05
# 16 ark      10 bark  Copy2     -0.1 
# 17 ark      20 bark  Copy2      0.12
# 18 ark      30 bark  Copy2      0.15
# 19 ark      40 bark  Copy2      0.22
# 20 ark      50 bark  Copy2      0.1 
# 21 bark     10 ad    Copy3     -0.1 
# 22 bark     20 ad    Copy3      0.01
# 23 bark     30 ad    Copy3      0.05
# 24 bark     40 ad    Copy3      0.06
# 25 bark     50 ad    Copy3      0.02
# 26 bark     10 ark   Copy3     -0.1 
# 27 bark     20 ark   Copy3      0.05
# 28 bark     30 ark   Copy3      0.1 
# 29 bark     40 ark   Copy3      0.2 
# 30 bark     50 ark   Copy3      0.3 
# 31 bark     10 bar   Copy2     -0.1 
# 32 bark     20 bar   Copy2      0.13
# 33 bark     30 bar   Copy2      0.25
# 34 bark     40 bar   Copy2      0.4 
# 35 bark     50 bar   Copy2      0.35
# 36 bark     10 bark  Copy2     -0.1 
# 37 bark     20 bark  Copy2      0.15
# 38 bark     30 bark  Copy2      0.3 
# 39 bark     40 bark  Copy2      0.7 
# 40 bark     50 bark  Copy2      0.7
```

So this succeeds in reducing the data to a single Copy for each Input x Word combination based on the maximum values in the Time 1..100 series.

The second challenge is to reduce that data to only the topX words per Input.

The approach @AnilGoyal suggested worked for simpler sample data, but due to an accidental contingency between the number of time steps included and the value of topX.

What I have been able to do so far, based on @AnilGoyal's example, is to identify the topX Words for each Input based on their maximum values. Here are 2 examples finding the top 3 and the top 2:

```
topX = 3
xftop3 <- xf2 %>% group_by(Input, Word) %>%
  slice_max(Value, with_ties=FALSE) %>%
  arrange(desc(Value)) %>%
  group_by(Input) %>%
  filter(1:n() <= topX) %>%
  arrange(Input, Value)

xftop3

# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   Input [2]
# Input  Time Word  copy_name Value
# <fct> <int> <fct> <chr>     <dbl>
# 1 ark      40 ad    Copy3      0.15
# 2 ark      40 bark  Copy2      0.22
# 3 ark      20 ark   Copy3      0.55
# 4 bark     50 ark   Copy3      0.3 
# 5 bark     40 bar   Copy2      0.4 
# 6 bark     40 bark  Copy2      0.7 

topX = 2
xftop2 <- xf2 %>% group_by(Input, Word) %>%
  slice_max(Value, with_ties=FALSE) %>%
  arrange(desc(Value)) %>%
  group_by(Input) %>%
  filter(1:n() <= topX) %>%
  arrange(Input, Value)

xftop2

# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   Input [2]
# Input  Time Word  copy_name Value
# <fct> <int> <fct> <chr>     <dbl>
# 1 ark      40 bark  Copy2      0.22
# 2 ark      20 ark   Copy3      0.55
# 3 bark     40 bar   Copy2      0.4 
# 4 bark     40 bark  Copy2      0.7
```

What I can't figure out how to do is then to use that tibble to reduce the data set to only those Input x Word combinations at all Times. The desired output for the sample data and topX = 2 would be:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 5
   Input  Time Word  copy_name Value
   <fct> <int> <fct> <chr>     <dbl>
 1 ark      10 ark   Copy3     -0.1 
 2 ark      20 ark   Copy3      0.55
 3 ark      30 ark   Copy3      0.2 
 4 ark      40 ark   Copy3      0.5 
 5 ark      50 ark   Copy3      0.4 
 6 ark      10 bark  Copy2     -0.1 
 7 ark      20 bark  Copy2      0.12
 8 ark      30 bark  Copy2      0.15
 9 ark      40 bark  Copy2      0.22
10 ark      50 bark  Copy2      0.1 
11 bark     10 bar   Copy2     -0.1 
12 bark     20 bar   Copy2      0.13
13 bark     30 bar   Copy2      0.25
14 bark     40 bar   Copy2      0.4 
15 bark     50 bar   Copy2      0.35
16 bark     10 bark  Copy2     -0.1 
17 bark     20 bark  Copy2      0.15
18 bark     30 bark  Copy2      0.3 
19 bark     40 bark  Copy2      0.7 
20 bark     50 bark  Copy2      0.7
```

I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Your problem is quite complex and you are using specific terms such as activation. You might want to rewrite it so you use common terms such as for instance "maximum value across these columns". As a non-NN-savvy myself, it would be much easier to answer your question. Also, could you give an example of your expected output?

Comment: @DanChaltiel, thank you for that advice. I edited to clarify the example in the ways you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: I tried to simplify the things.  Still it is too complex to read.  What the criteria for two words which are fixed for every Input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This answer has been rewritten (twice), see the edition log for the record.

There are two steps to your problem:

- 1. find the max values
- 2. select the rows that pertain to those max values

Finding the max value is a simple matter of filtering. However, you might have wanted to select the Input-Word pairs based on the mean/median across all times, instead of the occurrence of the max on a single time. This would be a matter of summarising (`dplyr::summarise()`.

Once you have the pairs, you simply need to select the right rows. There might be lots of ways, but I chose to use `right_join()`.

I chose to separate these steps for didactic purpose, but you can obviously merge them into one pipeline.

```r
topX=2
xf2bis = xf2 %>% 
  group_by(Input, Word) %>%
  filter(rank(Value, ties.method="first") == n()) %>% 
  group_by(Input) %>%
  filter(rank(Value, ties.method="first") > n() - topX) %>% 
  select(Input, Word)
xf2bis
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#> # Groups:   Input [2]
#>   Input Word 
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 ark   ark  
#> 2 ark   bark 
#> 3 bark  bar  
#> 4 bark  bark

xftop2 = xf2 %>% 
  right_join(xf2bis, by=c("Input", "Word"))
  
xftop2 
#> # A tibble: 20 x 5
#>    Input  Time Word  copy_name Value
#>    <chr> <int> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
#>  1 ark      10 ark   Copy3     -0.1 
#>  2 ark      10 bark  Copy2     -0.1 
#>  3 ark      20 ark   Copy3      0.55
#>  4 ark      20 bark  Copy2      0.12
#>  5 ark      30 ark   Copy3      0.2 
#>  6 ark      30 bark  Copy2      0.15
#>  7 ark      40 ark   Copy3      0.5 
#>  8 ark      40 bark  Copy2      0.22
#>  9 ark      50 ark   Copy3      0.4 
#> 10 ark      50 bark  Copy2      0.1 
#> 11 bark     10 bar   Copy2     -0.1 
#> 12 bark     10 bark  Copy2     -0.1 
#> 13 bark     20 bar   Copy2      0.13
#> 14 bark     20 bark  Copy2      0.15
#> 15 bark     30 bar   Copy2      0.25
#> 16 bark     30 bark  Copy2      0.3 
#> 17 bark     40 bar   Copy2      0.4 
#> 18 bark     40 bark  Copy2      0.7 
#> 19 bark     50 bar   Copy2      0.35
#> 20 bark     50 bark  Copy2      0.7
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Ah -- I just realized there's a slight problem with this solution. What we need is to select ONE copy of each word and discard all the others. In this solution, for example, Copy1 is selected for bark at Time 1, while Copy2 is selected at Tiimes 50 and 100. What I'm looking for is a way that would find the CopyX that has the max for a word, and then keep only that column and discard the others. Any suggestions? I'll post a solution if I can figure it out, but I've hit a wall so far.

Comment: I've edited the original post to clarify.

Comment: @user20412 sorry, it is a bit hard to understand it all, would you mind sharing the exact expected output from `ddf`?

Comment: @user20412 Still, here is another way that might suit your needs better. I will change the grouping based on your expected output.

Comment: thank you so much for your advice. I'm learning a lot from this! The pivot_longer approach doesn't quite get it. It still selects the Copy for a Word with the maximum at each Time, rather than find the Copy for each word that has the maximum over ALL time steps. I've edited the post to include a new data set where the maxima are different at different time steps. I've included the desired output to clarify. Thank you again.

Comment: Progress! The following identifies the correct instance for each Input,Word combo with the max value. Now need to use that Input,Word,copy_name to select correct column for each word:


df %>%
pivot_longer(starts_with("Copy"), names_to="copy_name", values_to="copy_value") %>% 
   group_by(Input, Word) %>% 
   filter(rank(copy_value, ties.method="first") == n()) %>%
   group_by(Input, Time)

Comment: @user20412 Sorry, there are far too much to read in your post. It is normal, it is difficult to ask a question. You don't have to keep all the previous attempts as anyone can check the edits logs if they want. Please state clearly what the maximum should be computed on at each stage. You seem to be close to your goal, keep going!

Comment: For instance, how do you get 0.05 on row 3?

Comment: I completely rewrote it. I hope it is more clear now! Thank you for your patience, advice, and improvements.

Comment: @user20412 your question improved a lot, that was fun to investigate! I think it will do now, as I get your expected output exactly :-) Also, if akrun answered your other question, don't forget to mark it as solved to earn him his due points.

Comment: welcome back, and thank you. I am embarrassed that I didn't realize that all I needed was a join. Please note that your solution works for topX = 2, but not for topX = 3. If you want the top 3 with this sample data, you actually have to set topX to 1. For the top4, you have to set it to 0. So it's returning all but the topX *bottom* slices. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Also, @DanChaltiel, the tibble returned after your `right_join` is all 40 lines. It seems to work if you swap xf2bis and xf2 in the command, that is, instead of `xftop2 = xf2bis %>% right_join(xf2, by=c("Input", "Word"))`, write it as `xftop2 = xf2 %>% 
  right_join(xf2bis, by=c("Input", "Word"))`. This returns 20 lines (top 2 words for both inputs). But see previous comment -- the topX does not behave as expected.

Comment: @user20412 Oops, yes I corrected the second filter for `topX` to work properly and switched the variable names (part of a test I was doing and removed wrong).

Comment: Hello, Dan Chaltiel. Thanks for your response. It looks like @AnilGoyal submitted a corrected solution a couple hours before you, and both work perfectly. Both would work fine, so I think stackoverflow etiquette would be to accept the answer that came first.

Comment: Ok, sorry for wavering, but I read that I should accept the solution that I will actually use in my work. Dan Chaltiel's approach is ~50% faster than @AnilGoyal's (which matters as I scale to dozens of full simulations of size 1000x1000x30x100), so I will accept this answer. I wish I could accept both. I'm very grateful for all the advice.

Answer (score 2):

What I understand till now, is that you need `semi_join` which only filters the data (left side) on the basis of row_combinations available in right data argument.

```
topX = 2
semi_join(xf2, xf2 %>% group_by(Input, Word) %>%
  slice_max(Value, with_ties=FALSE) %>%
  group_by(Input) %>%
  slice_max(Value, n= topX, with_ties = FALSE) %>%
  select(Input, Word), by = c('Input', 'Word'))

# A tibble: 20 x 5
   Input  Time Word  copy_name Value
   <chr> <int> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
 1 ark      10 ark   Copy3     -0.1 
 2 ark      10 bark  Copy2     -0.1 
 3 ark      20 ark   Copy3      0.55
 4 ark      20 bark  Copy2      0.12
 5 ark      30 ark   Copy3      0.2 
 6 ark      30 bark  Copy2      0.15
 7 ark      40 ark   Copy3      0.5 
 8 ark      40 bark  Copy2      0.22
 9 ark      50 ark   Copy3      0.4 
10 ark      50 bark  Copy2      0.1 
11 bark     10 bar   Copy2     -0.1 
12 bark     10 bark  Copy2     -0.1 
13 bark     20 bar   Copy2      0.13
14 bark     20 bark  Copy2      0.15
15 bark     30 bar   Copy2      0.25
16 bark     30 bark  Copy2      0.3 
17 bark     40 bar   Copy2      0.4 
18 bark     40 bark  Copy2      0.7 
19 bark     50 bar   Copy2      0.35
20 bark     50 bark  Copy2      0.7
```

---

Your second part will be solved by this code

```
topX <- 2L
xf2 %>% semi_join(xf2 %>% group_by(Input) %>%
  slice_max(Value, n= topX) %>% select(Input, Word), by = c("Input", "Word"))

# A tibble: 12 x 5
   Input  Time Word  copy_name Value
   <chr> <int> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
 1 ark       1 ark   Copy3      0   
 2 ark       1 bark  Copy2      0   
 3 ark      50 ark   Copy3      0.05
 4 ark      50 bark  Copy2      0.06
 5 ark     100 ark   Copy3      0.55
 6 ark     100 bark  Copy2      0.2 
 7 bark      1 bar   Copy2      0   
 8 bark      1 bark  Copy2      0   
 9 bark     50 bar   Copy2      0.7 
10 bark     50 bark  Copy2      0.75
11 bark    100 bar   Copy2      0.4 
12 bark    100 bark  Copy2      0.6
```

I think as a first part you can use this `semi_join` too Please check

```
xf %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Copy'), names_to = 'copy_name', 
               values_to = 'Value') %>% 
  semi_join(xf %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Copy'), names_to = 'copy_name', 
                                values_to = 'Value') %>% 
              group_by(Input, Word) %>%
              slice_max(Value) %>%
              select(Input, Word, copy_name), 
            by = c('Input', 'Word', 'copy_name')) -> xf2
```

Comment: Nice, @AnilGoyal! The first part works perfectly; the output is exactly what I listed as the 'desired output'. Your second part does not work because it chooses the top copies at Input x Time x Word, so it has different copies of words at different times. If you compare its output to the desired output, you'll see it's different from the desired output in several places. I don't know if there is a way to combine these into a single step. Maybe you should modify to remove the second part, and then I could accept this as the answer?

Comment: Thank you again, @AnilGoyal. For the first part, the desired output is the tibble printed out after `print(xf2, n = nrow(xf2))` in the question. It would be fine to do it in 1 step. I'll compare the various approaches for timing with the real data set. One thing I've learned so far is that pivot_longer is super fast compared to the map approaches I've tried so far (about 3x faster that future_map methods that I've tried).

Comment: your solution worked with the original example data because of accidental contingencies in the number of Time steps included and the values for various rows. But with expanded data (see revised question) with more time steps and more words (allowing one to use values of topX > 2), your solution doesn't quite work. I used your example to develop a partial solution, but I am still stuck in trying to select the topX Words for each Input (based on those Input x Word maxima over the whole time series).

Comment: Thank you very much. As I noted above in response to @DanChaltiel, both your answer and his produce the correct output robustly. I read that I should accept the solution I will actually use in my work. With real data, where each of my simulations has size 1000x1000x30x100, DanChaltiel's solution is about 50% faster, so I will use that one. I wish I could accept both answers. I'm very grateful for your advice on this, and I have upvoted your answer, of course.

Comment: No issues.  Accepting the answer is purely a personal choice.