# Reduce grouped data based on maximum of multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have datasets like this example, but with 1000 Inputs and 1000 Words for each Input, and 30 values for each Input x Time x Word combination (in cols Copy1..Copy30)

```
df = read.table(header=T, sep=",", text="
Input,Time,Word,Copy1,Copy2,Copy3,Copy30
ark,1,ark,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
ark,1,ad,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
ark,1,bark,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
ark,50,ark,0.00,0.10,0.05,0.00
ark,50,ad,0.00,0.05,0.03,0.00
ark,50,bark,0.07,0.06,0.00,0.00
ark,100,ark,0.00,0.17,0.55,0.00
ark,100,ad,0.00,0.03,0.11,0.00
ark,100,bark,0.05,0.20,0.00,0.00
bark,1,ark,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
bark,1,ad,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
bark,1,bark,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
bark,50,ark,0.00,0.03,0.09,0.00
bark,50,ad,0.00,0.05,0.03,0.00
bark,50,bark,0.2,0.75,0.00,0.00
bark,100,ark,0.00,0.08,0.32,0.00
bark,100,ad,0.00,0.03,0.11,0.00
bark,100,bark,0.21,0.60,0.00,0.00
") %>% arrange(Input,Time,Word)

df
# Input Time Word Copy1 Copy2 Copy3 Copy30
# 1    ark    1   ad  0.00  0.00  0.00      0
# 2    ark    1  ark  0.00  0.00  0.00      0
# 3    ark    1 bark  0.00  0.00  0.00      0
# 4    ark   50   ad  0.00  0.05  0.03      0
# 5    ark   50  ark  0.00  0.10  0.05      0
# 6    ark   50 bark  0.07  0.06  0.00      0
# 7    ark  100   ad  0.00  0.03  0.11      0
# 8    ark  100  ark  0.00  0.17  0.55      0
# 9    ark  100 bark  0.05  0.20  0.00      0
# 10  bark    1   ad  0.00  0.00  0.00      0
# 11  bark    1  ark  0.00  0.00  0.00      0
# 12  bark    1 bark  0.00  0.00  0.00      0
# 13  bark   50   ad  0.00  0.05  0.03      0
# 14  bark   50  ark  0.00  0.03  0.09      0
# 15  bark   50 bark  0.20  0.75  0.00      0
# 16  bark  100   ad  0.00  0.03  0.11      0
# 17  bark  100  ark  0.00  0.08  0.32      0
# 18  bark  100 bark  0.21  0.60  0.00      0
```

I want to group by Input and Word, and for each combination, determine which Copy column has the maximum value for each word, and then keep only that column for that Word for that Input. A response to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67272744/handling-enormous-nested-datasets-in-r-tidyr) got me part of the way there. This code identifies which Copy of each Word is the maximum.

```
max_copy <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Copy"), names_to="copy_name", values_to="copy_value") %>% 
  group_by(Input, Word) %>% 
  filter(rank(copy_value, ties.method="first") == n()) %>%
  group_by(Input, Time)

max_copy
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   Input, Time [3]
# Input  Time Word  copy_name copy_value
# <fct> <int> <fct> <chr>          <dbl>
# 1 ark     100 ad    Copy3           0.11
# 2 ark     100 ark   Copy3           0.55
# 3 ark     100 bark  Copy2           0.2 
# 4 bark     50 bark  Copy2           0.75
# 5 bark    100 ad    Copy3           0.11
# 6 bark    100 ark   Copy3           0.32
```

Now what I want to do is use this to reduce the data to the identified copies for each word for each input, so that the result would be:

```
# A tibble: 18 x 5
# Groups:   Input, Time [6]
#   Input  Time Word  copy_name copy_value
#   <fct> <int> <fct> <chr>          <dbl>
#  1 ark       1 ad    Copy3          0 
#  2 ark       1 ark   Copy3          0   
#  3 ark       1 bark  Copy2          0   
#  4 ark      50 ad    Copy3          0.03 
#  5 ark      50 ark   Copy3          0.05 
#  6 ark      50 bark  Copy2          0.06
#  7 ark     100 ad    Copy3          0.11 
#  8 ark     100 ark   Copy3          0.55
#  9 ark     100 bark  Copy2          0.2 
# 10 bark      1 ad    Copy3          0 
# 11 bark      1 ark   Copy3          0   
# 12 bark      1 bark  Copy2          0   
# 13 bark     50 ad    Copy3          0.03
# 14 bark     50 ark   Copy3          0.09
# 15 bark     50 bark  Copy2          0.75
# 16 bark    100 ad    Copy3          0.11
# 17 bark    100 ark   Copy3          0.32
# 18 bark    100 bark  Copy2          0.6
```

Is there a method where I can use the max_copy data to reduce df like this?

EDIT: There are problems with some solutions below. @akrun's solution breaks if there are negative values (easy to deal with) **or** if there are positive values in later Copies than the Copy with the maximum value (I can't see how to fix this). @AnoushiravanR's solution appears to be robust against both conditions, and so do the solutions from @AnilGoyal. Here's an updated dataset with those kinds of conditions included.

```
df2 = read.table(header=T, sep=",", text="
Input,Time,Word,Copy1,Copy2,Copy3,Copy30
ark,1,ark,0.00,0.00,0.00,-0.01
ark,1,ad,0.00,0.00,0.00,-0.01
ark,1,bark,0.00,0.00,0.00,-0.01
ark,1,bar,0.00,0.00,0.00,-0.01
ark,50,ark,0.00,0.10,0.05,-0.01
ark,50,ad,0.00,0.05,0.03,-0.01
ark,50,bark,0.07,0.06,0.01,-0.01
ark,50,bar,0.07,0.06,0.01,-0.01
ark,100,ark,0.00,0.17,0.55,-0.01
ark,100,ad,0.00,0.03,0.11,-0.01
ark,100,bark,0.05,0.20,0.01,-0.01
ark,100,bar,0.04,0.15,0.01,-0.01
bark,1,ark,0.00,0.00,0.00,-0.01
bark,1,ad,0.00,0.00,0.00,-0.01
bark,1,bark,0.00,0.00,0.00,-0.01
bark,1,bar,0.00,0.00,0.00,-0.01
bark,50,ark,0.00,0.03,0.09,-0.01
bark,50,ad,0.00,0.05,0.03,-0.01
bark,50,bark,0.2,0.75,0.01,0.01
bark,50,bar,0.2,0.7,0.00,-0.01
bark,100,ark,0.00,0.08,0.32,-0.01
bark,100,ad,0.00,0.03,0.11,-0.01
bark,100,bark,0.21,0.60,0.01,-0.01
bark,100,bar,0.15,0.4,0.01,-0.01
") %>% arrange(Input,Time,Word)
```

Desired output for df2:

```
# A tibble: 24 x 5
# Input  Time Word  copy_name Value
# <fct> <int> <fct> <chr>     <dbl>
# 1 ark       1 ad    Copy3      0   
# 2 ark       1 ark   Copy3      0   
# 3 ark       1 bar   Copy2      0   
# 4 ark       1 bark  Copy2      0   
# 5 ark      50 ad    Copy3      0.03
# 6 ark      50 ark   Copy3      0.05
# 7 ark      50 bar   Copy2      0.06
# 8 ark      50 bark  Copy2      0.06
# 9 ark     100 ad    Copy3      0.11
# 10 ark    100 ark   Copy3      0.55
# 11 ark    100 bar   Copy2      0.15
# 12 ark    100 bark  Copy2      0.2 
# 13 bark     1 ad    Copy3      0   
# 14 bark     1 ark   Copy3      0   
# 15 bark     1 bar   Copy2      0   
# 16 bark     1 bark  Copy2      0   
# 17 bark    50 ad    Copy3      0.03
# 18 bark    50 ark   Copy3      0.09
# 19 bark    50 bar   Copy2      0.7 
# 20 bark    50 bark  Copy2      0.75
# 21 bark   100 ad    Copy3      0.11
# 22 bark   100 ark   Copy3      0.32
# 23 bark   100 bar   Copy2      0.4 
# 24 bark   100 bark  Copy2      0.6
```

Comment: I have a doubt for the 'copy_name' why you have 'Copy3', 'Copy2' for the first 4 rows when they are 0.  Should that be Copy30

Comment: The idea is to choose 1 copy for each word based on its maximum over the entire time series for 1 input...

Comment: But, your `max_copy` objects doesn't have some values like 0.09 in the expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with `summarise`.  After reshaping to 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, do a group by 'Input', 'Time' Word', then `summarise` to create the 'copy_value' based on a condition that `if` `all` values are 0 then return 0 or `else` return the `last` non-zero value of 'copy_value'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Copy'), names_to = 'copy_name', 
        values_to = 'copy_value') %>% 
  group_by(Input, Time, Word) %>% 
  summarise(copy_value = if(all(copy_value == 0)) 0 
       else last(copy_value[copy_value != 0]), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 18 x 4
#   Input  Time Word  copy_value
# * <chr> <int> <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 ark       1 ad          0   
# 2 ark       1 ark         0   
# 3 ark       1 bark        0   
# 4 ark      50 ad          0.03
# 5 ark      50 ark         0.05
# 6 ark      50 bark        0.06
# 7 ark     100 ad          0.11
# 8 ark     100 ark         0.55
# 9 ark     100 bark        0.2 
#10 bark      1 ad          0   
#11 bark      1 ark         0   
#12 bark      1 bark        0   
#13 bark     50 ad          0.03
#14 bark     50 ark         0.09
#15 bark     50 bark        0.75
#16 bark    100 ad          0.11
#17 bark    100 ark         0.32
#18 bark    100 bark        0.6
```

---

If we need the 'copy_name' as well, then use the same logical expression in `slice` to return the row that meets the condition i.e. `if` `all` values are 0, return last row (`n()` - doesn't matter) or get the index of `last` non-zero of copy_value.  Now, we do a group by 'Input', 'Word' and `mutate` the 'copy_name' by replacing those with the corresponding 'copy_name' where the 'copy_value' is `max`

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Copy'), names_to = 'copy_name', 
        values_to = 'copy_value') %>% 
  group_by(Input, Time, Word) %>%
  arrange(copy_value) %>% 
  slice(if(all(copy_value <= 0)) n() 
       else tail(which(copy_value > 0), 1))%>% 
  group_by(Input, Word) %>% 
  mutate(copy_name = copy_name[which.max(copy_value)]) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 18 x 5
#   Input  Time Word  copy_name copy_value
#   <chr> <int> <chr> <chr>          <dbl>
# 1 ark       1 ad    Copy3           0   
# 2 ark       1 ark   Copy3           0   
# 3 ark       1 bark  Copy2           0   
# 4 ark      50 ad    Copy3           0.03
# 5 ark      50 ark   Copy3           0.05
# 6 ark      50 bark  Copy2           0.06
# 7 ark     100 ad    Copy3           0.11
# 8 ark     100 ark   Copy3           0.55
# 9 ark     100 bark  Copy2           0.2 
#10 bark      1 ad    Copy3           0   
#11 bark      1 ark   Copy3           0   
#12 bark      1 bark  Copy2           0   
#13 bark     50 ad    Copy3           0.03
#14 bark     50 ark   Copy3           0.09
#15 bark     50 bark  Copy2           0.75
#16 bark    100 ad    Copy3           0.11
#17 bark    100 ark   Copy3           0.32
#18 bark    100 bark  Copy2           0.6
```

Comment: @akrun this is very close but not quite. The idea is that for each Input x Word combination, we will select one Copy and retain that copy at every Time, even if the value is 0. Your solution selects Copy30 at Time = 1 for all words, but it should be the same CopyXs as at the other time steps. Any ideas?

Comment: @user20412 i guess the updated output matches your expecteddd. please check

Comment: That's beautiful, thank you. I will have to study it to understand, but I'm very grateful!

Comment: Dear @akrun I finally made some modification to get to the desired output. Thank you for all of your supports and encouragements.

Comment: Just edited to add a dataset that shows ways that the solution breaks -- if there are negative values (easy to fix) or if there are positive values in later Copies than the Copy with the maximum value (not sure how to fix this).

Comment: @user20412 All of the answerers posted solutions based on your initial data.  By changing the input, it is kind of creating a new question here

Comment: @akrun, I agree that saying I want to handle negative values is a change that might not be anticipated. But if the solution worked for the example data because it used the 'rightmost' Copy positive value rather than the actual maximum across all Copies, that solution was not correct -- even if it generated the desired output. I appreciate the time and effort you put into it. I'm curious if there's a way to ensure your approach chooses the maximum Copy even if there are 'later' copies that have positive values, as your method is very fast... Do you see a way to do that?

Comment: @user20412 akrun is quite right. When we have a sample data set to work with, we try to come up with a solution that best fits that set of data. And of course there may be so many scenarios involved that the we were not aware of. So it would be best to provide a data set that captures every range of variables and all possible outcomes.

Comment: I appreciate that the sample data did not have enough complexity to capture situations like ties and negative numbers. But consider an analogy. Suppose the question was how to find the address of the max value in a matrix, and in the sample data, the max was in the rightmost, lowermost non-zero address. A solution that returned the rightmost, lowermost non-zero value would work for the sample data, but would clearly not work for many other matrices.

Comment: @akrun, your solution will work with these changes. (1) Change `==0` to `<=0` and `!=0` to `>0`; that extends it to handle negative values. (2) Insert `arrange(copy_value) %>%` after the `group_by(Input, Time, Word) %>%` line; this ensures taking the max value and handles ties.

Comment: I made those changes

Comment: Thanks, Akrun. You did not include the `arrange(copy_value) %>%` after `group_by(Input, Time, Word)` in your update. Your update works on the old data but not the new data I added that demonstrates the problem (please see df2 in the updated question). If you add that arrange step, I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Solution**

I have updated my solution with your new data set. I couldn't see problem with the output but if there is anything that needs modifications I would be glad to know.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)


df2 %>%
  mutate(Copy_value = pmap_dbl(df2 %>% select(Copy1:Copy30), ~ max(c(...))),
         Copy_name = pmap(df2 %>% select(Copy1:Copy30), ~ 
                            names(c(...)[c(...) == max(c(...))]))) %>%
  unnest(Copy_name) %>% 
  group_by(Input, Word) %>%
  mutate(Copy_name = Copy_name[which.max(Copy_value)]) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  select(-c(Copy1:Copy_value)) %>%
  right_join(df2, by = c("Input", "Time", "Word")) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Copy_value = map_dbl(Copy_name, ~ get({.x}))) %>%
  select(-c(Copy1:Copy30))
```

**Output**
This is the output of the newly-provided data set.

```
   Input Time Word Copy_name Copy_value
1    ark    1   ad     Copy3       0.00
2    ark    1  ark     Copy3       0.00
3    ark    1  bar     Copy2       0.00
4    ark    1 bark     Copy2       0.00
5    ark   50   ad     Copy3       0.03
6    ark   50  ark     Copy3       0.05
7    ark   50  bar     Copy2       0.06
8    ark   50 bark     Copy2       0.06
9    ark  100   ad     Copy3       0.11
10   ark  100  ark     Copy3       0.55
11   ark  100  bar     Copy2       0.15
12   ark  100 bark     Copy2       0.20
13  bark    1   ad     Copy3       0.00
14  bark    1  ark     Copy3       0.00
15  bark    1  bar     Copy2       0.00
16  bark    1 bark     Copy2       0.00
17  bark   50   ad     Copy3       0.03
18  bark   50  ark     Copy3       0.09
19  bark   50  bar     Copy2       0.70
20  bark   50 bark     Copy2       0.75
21  bark  100   ad     Copy3       0.11
22  bark  100  ark     Copy3       0.32
23  bark  100  bar     Copy2       0.40
24  bark  100 bark     Copy2       0.60
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. I'm trying to puzzle through the steps to understand how it works. It seems I cannot extend it to my actual data because the memory demands are too great (it's crashing R on my linux box, whereas the pivot_longer solution can handle the enormous actual datasets quickly w/o memory issues). I'm trying to see if I can identify which steps are causing the main memory issues.

Comment: Your welcome. There is no doubt that pivoting is always faster than using for example `pmap` in this case. I already benchmarked them on various questions and saw the considerable difference but here I wanted to use a solution which was stable and more likely led to the desired output. But it's weird that you experience such problem. I think the first two lines are the most expensive and may slow down the code a bit. But in case you would like to handle an enormous data set `data.table` package solution may be the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

One more approach through `purrr`

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Copy'), names_to = 'copy_name', 
               values_to = 'Value') %>%
  semi_join(df %>% nest(copy_name = !c(Input, Word)) %>%
              mutate(copy_name = map_chr(copy_name, 
                                    ~ names(.x)[1 + which(.x[-1] == max(.x[-1]), arr.ind = T)[2]])),
            by = c("Input", "Word", "copy_name")
            )

# A tibble: 18 x 5
   Input  Time Word  copy_name Value
   <chr> <int> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
 1 ark       1 ad    Copy3      0   
 2 ark       1 ark   Copy3      0   
 3 ark       1 bark  Copy2      0   
 4 ark      50 ad    Copy3      0.03
 5 ark      50 ark   Copy3      0.05
 6 ark      50 bark  Copy2      0.06
 7 ark     100 ad    Copy3      0.11
 8 ark     100 ark   Copy3      0.55
 9 ark     100 bark  Copy2      0.2 
10 bark      1 ad    Copy3      0   
11 bark      1 ark   Copy3      0   
12 bark      1 bark  Copy2      0   
13 bark     50 ad    Copy3      0.03
14 bark     50 ark   Copy3      0.09
15 bark     50 bark  Copy2      0.75
16 bark    100 ad    Copy3      0.11
17 bark    100 ark   Copy3      0.32
18 bark    100 bark  Copy2      0.6
```

Actually, this cn be broken into two parts -

- first is through nesting and `purrr::map_chr` wherein names of those copies are found where the copy value is maximum for any Time value.

```
df %>% nest(copy_name = !c(Input, Word)) %>%
              mutate(copy_name = map_chr(copy_name, 
                                    ~ names(.x)[1 + which(.x[-1] == max(.x[-1]), arr.ind = T)[2]]))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Input Word  copy_name
  <chr> <chr> <chr>    
1 ark   ad    Copy3    
2 ark   ark   Copy3    
3 ark   bark  Copy2    
4 bark  ad    Copy3    
5 bark  ark   Copy3    
6 bark  bark  Copy2
```

- second part in joining pivoted data back with this data through `semi_join` which is actually a filtered join.

---

Another approach in single pipe

```
df %>% nest(data = !c(Input, Word)) %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~ .x %>% 
                      select(Time, 1+which(.x[-1] == max(.x[-1]), arr.ind = T)[2]) %>%
                      mutate(copy = names(.)[2]) %>%
                      rename_with(~'value', 2)
                    )) %>%
  unnest(data)

# A tibble: 18 x 5
   Input Word   Time value copy 
   <chr> <chr> <int> <dbl> <chr>
 1 ark   ad        1  0    Copy3
 2 ark   ad       50  0.03 Copy3
 3 ark   ad      100  0.11 Copy3
 4 ark   ark       1  0    Copy3
 5 ark   ark      50  0.05 Copy3
 6 ark   ark     100  0.55 Copy3
 7 ark   bark      1  0    Copy2
 8 ark   bark     50  0.06 Copy2
 9 ark   bark    100  0.2  Copy2
10 bark  ad        1  0    Copy3
11 bark  ad       50  0.03 Copy3
12 bark  ad      100  0.11 Copy3
13 bark  ark       1  0    Copy3
14 bark  ark      50  0.09 Copy3
15 bark  ark     100  0.32 Copy3
16 bark  bark      1  0    Copy2
17 bark  bark     50  0.75 Copy2
18 bark  bark    100  0.6  Copy2
```

Comment: These are neat solutions. They seem to break, though, if there are ties in the max values. For example, if you change the value of Copy2 of bark at Time 100 to 0.75 (same as it is at Time 50), it selects Copy3. With my full dataset, I'm finding cases where it doesn't select ANY Copy for a word when there are ties. Any advice, @AnilGoyal?